# mysqli migration issue and security advices

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to migrate from mysql to mysqli but this code doesn't work. I'm new to php and mysql

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");

/* check connection */ 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { printf("Connect failed: %s\n", 
mysqli_connect_error()); exit(); }

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid'")) {

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {

mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET array='$array' WHERE uid='$uid'");

}
else {mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users (uid,array) VALUES ('$uid','$array')"); }

mysqli_free_result($result); }

/* close connection */ 
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

So my questions are:

1. what should be changed to make this code work;
2. what security vulnerabilities does this code have and what changes in the code would you suggest to fix that?

Thanks for spending time to answer my questions.

Comment: "doesn't work" is oh-so-useful for trying to figure out the problem? Doesn't work... how? can't connect? queries fail? wrong data returned? crashes your server? melts down your data center? kicks your dog? you could vastly simplify the code with an `insert ... on duplicate key` construct, making it MUCH easier to maintain.

Comment: well, then add `... or die(mysqli_error())` to your query calls. That's basic debugging, and you should be doing it yourself, instead of flailing around in the dark.

Comment: I looked through the error log and saw there was a syntax error in php file. Actually this code works fine (I forgot to remove a curly brace in my file). Thanks for the response. Can you say something about security vulnerabilities by looking at this code?

Comment: you're using mysqli, but still inserting variable values directly into queries. no idea where those vars get their values from, but it CAN be open to sql injection attacks. You should be using prepared statements with placeholders instead. The code's also racy. Nothing says some OTHER script can't swoop in and insert a record that the original `select` said didn't exist, before this script has a chance to do its own insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to set error reporting to maximum level and make error messages available. this way you will let PHP to tell you what is going wrong and what needs to be fixed.

   - however, sometimes our code still doesn't work yet there are no error messages around. it's time to do some *debugging*
2. You have to change this code to make **every** variable to go into query via **placeholder only**

however, raw mysqli is extremely bad with prepared statements, so, I would recommend not to use it but rather move toward [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) or [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql#safemysql). A latter one will let you to have *safe* queries with the same amount of code.

```
if ($db->getOne("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE uid=?i",$uid))
{
    $db->query("UPDATE users SET array=?s WHERE uid=?i",$array,$uid);

} else {

    $db->query("INSERT INTO users (uid,array) VALUES (?i,?s)",$uid,$array);
}
```

By the way, Mysql lets you to make all these three queries in *one*:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (uid, array) VALUES (?i,?s) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE array=values(array)";
$db->query($sql, $uid, $array);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response!